# JPA Hibernate Performance

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using Mysql, Springboot with JPA Hibernate.

Now to query using JPA, I have 2-3 options:

1. Using functionNames as direct query like `findById()` and soon
2. Using JPQL
3. Using Native Query in my SpringBoot JPA Repository (using nativeQuery = true)
4. Using CustomRepo and then write SQL and fire query using Hibernate Entity Manager

Now what will be performance in all four cases?

I mean which method is most optimized and which is least and reason?

Comment: Imho native insertion into JPA project are wrong (when unneeded). a) & b) I guess equal after first fire. If U want extremly high performance, few non JPA low-level mapperrs with good opinion exist. Of-course assume exist index on Id

Comment: All will have basically the same performance. What matters is the query, and its execution plan (indices, etc.). But if you use JPA, using SQL is counter-productive. Ue what is the easiest to understand and maintain, and only optimize if needed.